# Using jquery how can I change an href value of an element with a certain CSS class?

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm looking for a way to find links with the "colorbox-load" class like this...

```
<a class="colorbox-load" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYVGKdop63Y?fs=1&amp;width=640&amp;height=480&amp;hl=en_US1&amp;iframe=true&amp;rel=0">Kendra Grittani on stage at Koerner Hall (broken)</a>
```

...and using jquery I want to replace every instance in the href tag of "youtube.com/watch?v=" with "youtube.com/v/".

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to do the find and replace.

```
$("a.colorbox-load").attr("href", "http://www.youtube.com") {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("youtube.com/watch?v=", "youtube.com/v/");
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a simple string [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

```
$("a.colorbox-load").each(function(){
  var newUrl = $(this).attr('href').replace('youtube.com/watch?v=', 'youtube.com/v/');
  $(this).attr('href', newUrl);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Created an example for you at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6QtL/)**.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, it's not working for me. I'm worried this might be because of something happening on my end so I'm going to play around with it for a bit more.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example. Try it out

Comment: Yup, it was my fault. This is what finally worked for me.

(function ($) {
 
 $('a.colorbox-load').each(function(){
   var newUrl = $(this).attr('href').replace('youtube.com/watch?v=', 'youtube.com/v/');
   $(this).attr('href', newUrl);
 });

})(jQuery);